# How do u convert a string into data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I'm performing an api request and I get this response back:

```
print(res)

b'amp,dev, util\n192.168.101.1,server123,80%\n192.168.101.4,serverabc,75%\n192.68.101.5,serverusa1,50%\n'
```

I need convert this string to a data frame:

```
Amp.          dev.      util
192.168.101.1 server123  80%
192.168.101.4 serverabc  75%
192.168.101.5 serverusa1 50%
```

I tried this.

```
 import pandas as pd
 pd.read_table(res, sep='\n')
```

Oserror: expected file path

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html). `pd.read_table` does not accept string input. It expects eg filepath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

res = b'amp,dev, util\n192.168.101.1,server123,80%\n192.168.101.4,serverabc,75%\n192.68.101.5,serverusa1,50%\n'

# Decode the byte string to a regular string
res = res.decode('utf-8')

data = res.split('\n')

# Delete last empty line
data = data[:-1]

# Convert List to DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(',') for x in data[1:]], columns=data[0].split(','))

print(df)
```

```
             amp         dev  util
0  192.168.101.1   server123   80%
1  192.168.101.4   serverabc   75%
2   192.68.101.5  serverusa1   50%
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) (or [`read_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html)) with [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO):

```
import io

res = b'amp,dev, util\n192.168.101.1,server123,80%\n192.168.101.4,serverabc,75%\n192.68.101.5,serverusa1,50%\n'

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(res.decode('utf-8')))

# or
# df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(res.decode('utf-8')), sep=',')
```

Output:

```
             amp         dev  util
0  192.168.101.1   server123   80%
1  192.168.101.4   serverabc   75%
2   192.68.101.5  serverusa1   50%
```